# Simple blink comparator for two images

Tags: dynamic

I tried to build a simple 'blink comparator' - where you can click on an image repeatedly to switch between two similar images. (An old-fashioned notion in the days of powerful image processing software, it's true.) I think the problem with what I've done so far is the behaviour of the symbols inside a `DynamicModule`:

```
image1 = Thumbnail[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], 300];
image2 = Thumbnail[
   ColorNegate[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}]], 300];
DynamicModule[{imageList = {image1, image2}},
 EventHandler[
  Show[
   First[imageList],
   Graphics[
    {
     Text[
      Style[
       "name of First[imageList]]?", 
       14, White],
      ImageDimensions[First[imageList]]/2]
     }
    ]],
  {"MouseDown" :> 
    {
     RotateLeft[imageList],
     Beep[]
     }
   }]]
```

[image: gratuitous mandrill picture]

The `Beep` confirms the `EventHandler` action, but the image doesn't change.

Comment: `RotateLeft` doesn't change the list inplace rather it creates a new one, so your `imageList` is never updated

Comment: Good point - but `imageList = RotateLeft[imageList],` doesn't seem to work...

Comment: `FlipView[{image1, image2}]`?

Comment: @rojo :) why didn't I search for 'flip'!? Looks like a much easier way than mine. Still, learning about `Dynamic` is always a good thing... :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to assign `imageList` for it to actually update, also you need to make the graphics dynamic for it to update when the list is changed. Code changes are:

```
... imageList = RotateLeft[imageList] ...
... EventHandler[Dynamic@Show[First[  ...
```

So it's :

```
image1 = Thumbnail[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], 300];
image2 = Thumbnail[
 ColorNegate[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}]], 300];
DynamicModule[{imageList = {image1, image2}}, 
 EventHandler[
 Dynamic@Show[First[imageList], 
  Graphics[{Text[Style["name of First[imageList]]?", 14, White], 
   ImageDimensions[First[imageList]]/
   2]}]], {"MouseDown" :> {imageList = RotateLeft[imageList], 
 Beep[]}}]]
```

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi, @jVincent, Don't forget to wrap `Show` in `Dynamic`.

Comment: @jVincent Thanks - works well. Any idea how to get the name of the currently displayed image (eg "image1") into the `Text` expression?

Comment: @cormullion You could simply define `names={"name1","name2"};` and also rotate it when you rotate the other list; `names = RotateLeft[names]`. Then ofcause switch out the string you use now with `First@names`.

Comment: OK. I'd been fiddling with something else - yours is easier.

Answer (score 16):

You can use [`FlipView`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FlipView.html)

```
FlipView[{image1, image2}]
```

Comment: That's cool Rojo, I never noticed FlipView before. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Yes, good find, @rojo!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a somewhat simpler approach using the Manipulate[] function:

```
 image1 = Thumbnail[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], 300];
 image2 = Thumbnail[ColorNegate[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}]], 300];
 Manipulate[If[t == 1, image1, image2], {t, {0, 1}}]
```

Each time you click on the checkbox, it alternates between the two images.